# Error Running Jython Script using WSADMIN

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I'm trying to write a simple script to restart the WebSphere application server.

Below is my script :

```
ManagedProcessList=AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=Server,*')

for i in range(len(ManagedProcessList)) :
        serverStatus=AdminControl.getAttribute(ManagedProcessList[i], 
'state')
        serverName=ManagedProcessList[i].split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
        nodeName=ManagedProcessList[i].split(',')[3].split('=')[1]

        if serverStatus == "STARTED":
                if nodeName in ("WC_node") and serverName in ("server1"):
                        print 
"restarting",serverName,"on",nodeName,"because it is 
currently",serverStatus
                        AdminControl.stopServer(serverName,nodeName)
                        AdminControl.startServer(serverName,nodeName)

    else:
                print "Not restarting",serverName,"on",nodeName,"because 
it is currently",serverStatus
```

Its returning the below error.

```
WASX7015E: Exception running command: 
wsadmin>execfile('/home/raja/serverstat.py')
"execfile('/home/raja/serverstat.py')"; exception information:
 com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in 
String "WebSphere:W"; cannot create ObjectName.
```

Command output looks like below :

```
wsadmin>print AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=Server,*')
WebSphere:name=server1,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=WC_node,j2eeType=J2EEServer,version=7.0.0.41,type=Server,mbeanIdentifier=cells/WC_cell/nodes/WC_node/servers/server1/server.xml#Server_1183144161046,cell=WC_cell,spec=1.0,processType=UnManagedProcess
wsadmin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the script as given below.

Changes.
1. use **splitlines** method to convert the result of "AdminControl.queryNames" to a list, in line 1
2. used **'=='** operator in IF condition statement at line 9, to check the nodename and servername

```
ManagedProcessList=AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=Server,*').splitlines()

for i in range(len(ManagedProcessList)) :
    serverStatus=AdminControl.getAttribute(ManagedProcessList[i], 'state')
    serverName=ManagedProcessList[i].split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
    nodeName=ManagedProcessList[i].split(',')[3].split('=')[1]

    if serverStatus == "STARTED":
        if nodeName == "WC_node" and serverName == "server1":
            print "restarting",serverName,"on",nodeName,"because it is currently",serverStatus
            AdminControl.stopServer(serverName,nodeName)
            AdminControl.startServer(serverName,nodeName)
        else:
            print "Not restarting",serverName,"on",nodeName,"because it is currently",serverStatus
```

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. Please also "accept" the answer if you are happy with my solution